# Loop and difference in chef template

Tags: ansible, chef-infra, chef-template

```
{% for peer_ip in all_ips.split(',') | difference([source_ip]) %}
    {{ peer_ip }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Where source ip is the ip address of the server where this is run and peer ip is the secondary ip for the same service. all_ips contains 2 ips of source and peer comma separated.

Like this ansible code, how do i write something similar for chef template erb as I am very new to chef.

Please direct me if there is a similar question out there, couldn't find much in my limited time

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am new to ansible. What does pipe (`|`), difference and source_ip are? Could you state in ordinary english (not in ansible), what data you have and what you need to get?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [template resource](https://docs.chef.io/templates/) with [embedded-ruby (erb)](https://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/)